# How can show a ghaphic indicator over Slingr low code platform?

Tags: slingr

I would like to add traffic light icon based on entity field value in given collection view. Are there some way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can apply to your case, but you can highlight a record in a collection view using the `Record highlight` feature in collection views (works on grid and cards views).

Basically, you can define conditions to decide if the record can be highlighted and which color will be used for that. You can find more information here:

https://slingr-stack.github.io/platform/app_development_ui_grid_views.html#record-highlight